# Null values in arraylist break lines in Androidplot

Tags: androidplot

I plot the graph with androidplot. calling values from database has null values in the arraylist. The x-axis values have a two corresponding y-values. The null y-value doesn't plot (which perfect) but breaks the line into two. I want the line to join leaving the null values out (point {5,5} should join point {7,8} without a break)

```
    Number[] xAlertseries1={3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    Number[] yAlertseries2={4,10,5,null,8,9,10};
    Number[] yActionseries={4,10,11,13,14,15,16};

XYSeries alertseries = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(xAlertseries1), Arrays.asList(yAlertseries2),"ALERT");
XYSeries actionseries = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(xAlertseries1), Arrays.asList(yActionseries),"ACTION");


        labprogplotter.addSeries(alertseries, actionalertformat);
        labprogplotter.addSeries(actionseries, actionalertformat);

        labprogplotter.redraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's funny i had to answer my own question. Yes, Bert

```
Number[] xAlertseries1={3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

//created a new xActionseries so that all have their own x-values
Number[] xActionseries={3,4,5,6,7,8,9};


Number[] yAlertseries2={4,10,5,null,8,9,10};
Number[] yActionseries={4,10,11,13,14,15,16};


 //iterated to remove null values in yAlertseries2 and its corresponding value in its x-values

 for(int i=0;i<yAlertseries2.size();i++)
    { if(yAlertseries2.get(i)==null) 
    {
        yAlertseries2.remove(i); 
        xAlertseries1.remove(i);
        i--;
    } }

XYSeries alertseries = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(xAlertseries1),    Arrays.asList(yAlertseries2),"ALERT");
XYSeries actionseries = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(xActionseries), Arrays.asList(yActionseries),"ACTION");


    labprogplotter.addSeries(alertseries, actionalertformat);
    labprogplotter.addSeries(actionseries, actionalertformat);

    labprogplotter.redraw()
```